# Why is there a "de" before "partout" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-lieu

> Il n'y a pas de touristes à Croix-Russe. Au vieux Lyon, il y en a **de** partout mais ici à Croix-Rousse non.

The *de* before the *partout* has me confused. Why would that be needed there? This is excerpted from [a youtube interview](https://youtu.be/ARjeK8cu8JY?t=2m40s) with someone on the streets of Croix-Rousse.

Comment: C'est la [Croix-R**o**usse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Croix-Rousse), quartier de Lyon. Je ne suis pas Lyonnais mais je pense qu'on mettrait des majuscules à Vieux Lyon, voire un tiret : [Vieux-Lyon](https://www.visiterlyon.com/de-la-presqu-ile-au-vieux-lyon.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is:

> Il n'y a pas de touristes à Croix-**Rousse**. Dans le **Vieux** Lyon, il y en a de partout mais ici à Croix-**Rousse** non.

Given the context, ***de partout*** likely means "**everywhere, all over the place**" in a colloquial French syntax, not "from everywhere".

cf. [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/partout):

> − Pop. **De partout**. De tous les côtés à la fois. J'étais plus mince sans corset qu'elle avec le sien qui craquait de partout (Barb. d'Aurev., Mémor. 1, 1837, p.155).Ça sonne de partout et on entend tout ça de là-haut (Giono, Gd troupeau, 1931, p.61).

Comment: Merci pour les corrections, quelques-uns étaient des fautes de frappe, des autres étaient écrit comme les a parlé le locuteur.

Comment: [Here it is](https://youtu.be/ARjeK8cu8JY?t=2m40s).

Comment: L'acception citée ne semble pas garantir une telle interprétation à mon sens. Il en va de même pour le contexte -- la provenance des touristes est très pertinente, non ?

Comment: @Luke Après avoir revu la video, je n'ai guère de doute sur le sens employé. L'origine des touristes n'est pas abordée, c'est bien de leur présence et de leur nombre dont il est question ici.

Comment: @jlliagre Hmm, je suis d'accord après l'avoir vue.

Answer (score -1):

La préposition *de* indique la provenance, il faut comprendre « Au Vieux Lyon il y en a qui sont originaires de partout (qui viennent de partout) ».

On pourrait, bien sûr avoir « il y en a partout », mais le sens serait différent, ça voudrait dire qu'il y a beaucoup de touristes, qu'ils sont partout.

Comment: No, in this sentence, the "de" does not indicate the provenance. It's weird, but it's an expression :(