# partout vs de partout

Tags: différence

If [*de partout* = "everywhere, all over the place"](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/27834), then how does *partout* differ from *de partout*?

If there is a difference, then what exactly does ***de*** mean in ***de** partout*?

Comment: As explained in the answer you are linking to the meaning of  *de partout* is very specific in the sentence quoted. So you should not generalize : *de partout* = "everywhere, all over the place", it is not what this answer says.

Comment: If we look at the [BtB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9XEF0LAJK9mU.html) it says *Cependant, de partout n’est pas admis au sens de « en tous lieux », « en de nombreux endroits », qui est propre à l’adverbe partout*. [Here as well](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/il-y-en-a-de-partout/) *le « de  » est vraiment superflu et n’ajoute rien à la phrase.  Il appartient au langage familier et doit éviter de se montrer dans un écrit soutenu.*.

Comment: Les citoyens venait **de partout** pour assister à [je-ne-sais-quoi]. **from** everywhere.  So, it depends.

Comment: Among occurrences of *de partout*, a fair number are here because the verb is used with preposition *de* to start with. `Ils viennent de partout en Europe`, `le sang lui coulait de partout`, etc. In contrast, the example you linked to is colloquial and more uncommon because *de* doesn't go naturally with the verb - you can always substitute it for the more correct *partout*. The opposite is not true.